# Convert image to byte array quickly

Tags: java, image

I am converting an image object into a byte array like this:

```
private byte[] getImageBytes() throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes;
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        ImageIO.write(copyImage(image), "png", baos);
        baos.flush();
        bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    }
    return bytes;
}

private BufferedImage copyImage(Image img) {
    BufferedImage copyOfImage = new BufferedImage(getSize().width, getSize().height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = copyOfImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    return copyOfImage;
}
```

The problem is, that it takes more than 300ms to convert a 90KB image. If the image's size is around 1.2MB then the conversion takes only moderately longer (around 450ms).
I have measured the time of the copyImage-method. It only takes around 1ms. The problem seems to be the ImageIO.write method.

Do you know of any way to speed this up?

Comment: Why are you allocating a 100K byte array in each call to `getImageBytes` and then basically ignoring it unless there's an error? And are you sure you *really* want to just return an array of 0s if there's an exception? (Why not handle the exception at a higher level?)

Comment: I updated the question with how it originally looked. That way I would get a NPE if `bytes` cannot be filled. I just thought that if I would initialize the array then it would save time. I see though that the initialization was irrelevant because of the new assignment. The initialization of the `new ByteArrayOutputStream` with a value didn't save much time either.

Comment: You'll only get an NPE because you're swallowing the exception - if you make the exception bubble up, you'll never get an NPE from it, because `baos.toByteArray()` will never return null. And no, initializing the array doesn't *save* time - it *costs* time. You're allocating a new array, and then in every success case, you're just letting it get garbage collected.

Comment: thank you. updated it again.

Comment: That's a lot better - although now I'd just get rid of the `bytes` variable entirely, and use `return baos.toByteArray();` :) So, does that change the timing at all? I think this *may* just be a limitation of the `ImageIO` implementation you're using. IIRC, it's pluggable - there may be faster implementations around.

Comment: Your _ImageIO.write_ call is compressing the data to PNG, which takes time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *getImageBytes()* you are compressing the image to PNG which can take time. The fastest ImageIO.write call you can achieve is

```
ImageIO.write(copyImage(image), "bmp", baos);
```

where there is no compression. Still, ImageIO contains reference implementations of image formats which are not designed for speed.

Comment: changing it to bmp reduces the time by 200 ms. Unfortunately it increases the byte array size dramatically. But since i was looking for speed at this point, this is the correct answer.